# Spring's @Scheduled is not firing at the expected intervals - missing a lot

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have the classes configured as such (I've cut out some for brevity):

- The business logic takes on average, 1 second or less to run.
- The application does have a few dozen @Scheduled annotations throughout

It does make a call to a DB (that hasn't yet crashed or run in to connection problems):

```
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(200);
        scheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
        scheduler.initialize();
        return scheduler;
    }

    ...
}  


@Service
public class SomeBusinessLogic {

    ...

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * * *")
    public void importanTask() {
        synchronized(lockProcess) {
            this.executeLogic();
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

I would expect to see the log messages every 10 minutes, but here is what I see:

```
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 00:00:00.119 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-193] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: [C
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 01:28:40.091 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-182] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 01:33:58.809 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-183] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 01:40:00.009 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-26] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 01:50:00.007 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-94] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 02:00:00.014 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-98] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: [Ca
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 03:13:46.469 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-25] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 03:23:14.383 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-128] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 03:30:00.008 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-128] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 03:40:00.007 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-191] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 03:50:00.006 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-190] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 04:00:00.011 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-138] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: [C
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 05:24:23.808 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-64] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 05:30:00.010 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-90] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 05:40:00.008 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-47] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 05:50:00.008 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-64] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 06:00:00.017 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-100] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 07:21:12.429 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-191] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 07:30:00.007 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-126] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 07:40:00.010 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-122] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
[WARN ] 2021-05-31 07:50:00.007 [threadPoolTaskScheduler-36] SomeBusinessLogic - ...: []
```

After restarting Tomcat, for about an hour, it's all good, I will see it every 10 minutes like I expect, but shortly there after, it gets very sporadic. this particular scheduled task is incredibly important.

I've increased the pool above to 200 with no success. Can I created maybe a new executor pool and just assign important tasks to that and have the other deal with everything else? If so, is there a decent example somewhere of how others have done that?

If that's not an option, is there a way to debug and see why I'm getting such sporadic scheduling even though I have a huge number of available threads?

Comment: I would put a log message first thing in the `@Scheduled` method. It's more likely something is preventing your business logic from executing rather than the `@Scheduled` method not firing.

Comment: Why `syncronized` that looks already fishy. You are doing a `this.executeLogic` which means if that is `@Transactional` nothing will happen and you potentially have a connection leak. The fact that it is synchronized and holds lets me believe the tasks either take longer than you think or you have a connection leak leading to an exhausted pool. Also do you really  need 200 threads? Threads are quite expensive.

Comment: @HopeyOne I did, I cut it out above, but the business logic, that log message is the first line, before the snychronized(...) block.

Comment: @M.Deinum I had stated above, I increased the thread pool size because it wasn't firing and that was always the prescribed fix. I just stated above, there is a log message before anything, even the synchronized block; I removed it here for brevity. The DB has 10K connections and we have never once gone above 250 - this is all monitored by multiple tools on both the app and the DB server.

One of the calls within the `this.executeLogic` is `@Transactional` - when it does run, which you see if periodically does, it works. there is an aspect which measures it less than 1 second

Comment: You have a connection pool of 10k connections?! I'm not considering the DB side the java side with the connection pool if that is exhausted things will stop. I'm still believing you have some resource issues and throwing more threads at it will not solve it (imho it will make things worse).

Comment: @M.Deinum Creating more threads isn't working, but it's all that previous answers suggested, so to avoid SO deleting the question because it was asked and answered, I wanted to call out that adding more threads definitely didn't work. I'm 99% confident it's not the DB...but I will see what I can do to more closely monitor that. 

I did check, and I have 150 DB connections on the Java side. I will try increasing that too just out of curiosity; that may actually be it...

Comment: Increasing connections isn't the solution either, you have a resource leak somewhere (at least that is what I think), adding more connections or increasing the resources will only delay the moment. Another thing you might want to do is, depending on the datasource you are using, is to enable idle connection checking and connection validation. That way you don't have stale connections in the pool (which might become an issue as well, as it might take a while to get a valid connection).

Comment: @M.Deinum I found it and you were right - it was related to the synchronized block. There's a separate reporting job that kicks off and locks the DB table that I'm updating, so every couple of hours, that synchronized block takes an hour and a half to run. So there's a lot to fix here, but just wanted to follow up. The connection pools will go back to the previous values (much, much lower). 

Thanks!